# Best way to disable Android game install banner from C2 game url

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-app, construct-2

How to disable @Android google web app install banner ?

On android 6 phones chrome started to display install banner, now our C2 games are installed to phone when user should be playing games on our website.

We prefer to allow usage on website only. What setting should we change on page to prevent the installation. We have https site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
  console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired');
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```